# Как подключить Raspberry pi по USB

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi

Нужно подключить raspberry к компьютеру через USB-USB кабель. На компьютере работает программа, она передает данные на usb (не файлы), а raspberry их принимает. Получается что-то вроде i2c но на USB.

Даже не знаю как это называется, и в какую сторону копать. Подскажите :)

Comment: Думаю для начала, Вам стоит покопать в сторону представления Raspberry Pi пк, как устройство

Comment: Простым кабелем никак. Разве что двумя USB-RS232 кабелями с соответствующим образом соединенными Rx-Tx выводами.

Comment: @artemgh а как это правильно называется. По запросу ничего не находится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот тут https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/271/can-i-use-raspberry-pi-as-a-usb-peripheral-device пишут, что «малинка» не может работать как ведомое уствройство. Наиболее удобный вариант - взять USB-uart переходник и подключить его uart к gpio-разъемам raspbery pi.

Comment: "«малинка» не может работать как ведомое уствройство" то-есть не может отдавать информацию?

Comment: В стандарте USB прописано, что одно устройство ведущее (хост), к которому подключается одно или несколько ведомых. Между собой нельзя напрямую соединить ни два ведущих, ни два ведомых. Между ведущим и ведомым информация может передаваться в обе стороны, и инициировать отправку может как одна так и другая сторона.

Comment: @Xrou Zero может, но нужны дрова

Answer (score 0):

> как это правильно называется

Это называется P2P - Point to Point протокол. Реализовать его через USB вряд-ли получится, т.к. в USB на одном конце должен обязательно быть Host. Т.е. соединение **не** равнозначное. Можно попробовать между USB включить преобразователь USB-UART, но не уверен, что из этого что-то получится. Посмотрите вот это обсуждение:

https://coderoad.ru/23870864/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-android-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-USB

Там про Андроид, но проблема таже.